# FreeBSD + Audio from Realtec ALC883 integrated in motherboard

Tags: freebsd

I have one integrated soundcard in motherboard with Realtec ALC883 chip(?) and one PCI sound card ESS Solo-1E. FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE
I need play differend mp3 on each of output. I have no problem with sound on PCI card, but can't understand, how to send sound form mpg123 to integrated soundcard (as I understand, there are no such device in /dev/).

`ls /dev/`:

```
acpi            atkbd0          devctl2         kbd1            mixer1          reroot          ttyv2           ttyvd           usbctl
ad0             audit           devstat         kbdmux0         mixer2          sndstat         ttyv3           ttyve           xpt0
ad0p1           bpf             dsp0.0          klog            mixer3          stderr          ttyv4           ttyvf           zero
ad0p2           bpf0            dumpdev         kmem            mixer4          stdin           ttyv5           ufssuspend
ad0p3           console         fd              log             nfslock         stdout          ttyv6           ugen0.1
ada0            consolectl      fido            lpt0            null            sysmouse        ttyv7           ugen1.1
ada0p1          ctty            geom.ctl        lpt0.ctl        pass0           ttyu0           ttyv8           ugen2.1
ada0p2          cuau0           gptid           mdctl           pci             ttyu0.init      ttyv9           ugen3.1
ada0p3          cuau0.init      hpet0           mem             ppi0            ttyu0.lock      ttyva           ugen4.1
apm             cuau0.lock      io              midistat        pts             ttyv0           ttyvb           urandom
apmctl          devctl          kbd0            mixer0          random          ttyv1           ttyvc           usb
```

dsp0.0 is for PCI card

`cat /dev/sndstat`:

```
Installed devices:
pcm0: <ESS Solo-1E> (play/rec) default
pcm1: <ATI R6xx (HDMI)> (play)
pcm2: <Realtek ALC883 (Rear Analog)> (play/rec)
pcm3: <Realtek ALC883 (Front Analog)> (play/rec)
pcm4: <Realtek ALC883 (Onboard Digital)> (play)
```

`cat /boot/loader.conf`:

```
snd_solo_load="YES"
snd_hda_load="YES"
```

Answer (score 1):

to list all avaliable sound devices (in my example 0 - PCI card, 2 - internal rear output)

```
root@012-music:/home/ishayahu # sysctl dev.pcm
....
dev.pcm.2.bitperfect: 0
dev.pcm.2.buffersize: 65536
dev.pcm.2.rec.autosrc: 2
dev.pcm.2.rec.32bit: 20
dev.pcm.2.rec.vchanformat: s16le:2.0
dev.pcm.2.rec.vchanrate: 48000
dev.pcm.2.rec.vchanmode: fixed
dev.pcm.2.rec.vchans: 1
dev.pcm.2.play.32bit: 24
dev.pcm.2.play.vchanformat: s16le:2.0
dev.pcm.2.play.vchanrate: 48000
dev.pcm.2.play.vchanmode: fixed
dev.pcm.2.play.vchans: 1
dev.pcm.2.%parent: hdaa1
dev.pcm.2.%pnpinfo:
dev.pcm.2.%location: nid=20,24,26
dev.pcm.2.%driver: pcm
dev.pcm.2.%desc: Realtek ALC883 (Rear Analog)dev.pcm.0.bitperfect: 0
...
dev.pcm.0.buffersize: 16384
dev.pcm.0.rec.vchanformat: s16le:2.0
dev.pcm.0.rec.vchanrate: 48000
dev.pcm.0.rec.vchanmode: fixed
dev.pcm.0.rec.vchans: 1
dev.pcm.0.play.vchanformat: s16le:2.0
dev.pcm.0.play.vchanrate: 48000
dev.pcm.0.play.vchanmode: fixed
dev.pcm.0.play.vchans: 1
dev.pcm.0.%parent: pci4
dev.pcm.0.%pnpinfo: vendor=0x125d device=0x1969 subvendor=0x125d subdevice=0x8888 class=0x040100
dev.pcm.0.%location: pci0:4:1:0
dev.pcm.0.%driver: pcm
dev.pcm.0.%desc: ESS Solo-1E
```

to play different files on differents outputs:

```
mpg123 -a /dev/dsp0.0 dir/file.mp3
mpg123 -a /dev/dsp2.0 dir2/file.mp3
```